# Magento 2 - "url_key" Product Attribute, force as required and unique

Tags: magento2, catalog, url

Is it good practice to force the "url_key" product attribute to be both "required" and "unique" by default?

```
update eav_attribute set is_required=1,is_unique=1 where attribute_code = "url_key";
```

As preventative cure for the common issue:

> URL key for specified store already exists